# Why is pepper flash sandboxed?

Tags: 16.04, flash, browser, opera

I have been using Opera for a few days with the new Ubuntu 16.04. I was about to log onto my online, work account from home. Our company website uses flash, but after clicking on the login button....nothing happens. I opened Opera from the terminal and got this error message

```
[WARNING:flash/platform/pepper/pep_module.cpp(63)] SANDBOXED
Vector smash protection is enabled.
```

Any clues what is really happening here?

Comment: It looks like upgrading flash player would solve the issue: https://forum.antergos.com/topic/5506/pepper-flash-update/11